# my mysql command line client password keeps changing automatically. i don't use it for a few weeks and it changes the password why does this happen?

Tags: mysql

I'm new to mysql and when i don't use it for a few days it changes the password somehow, on it's own.
i've had to reinstall it so many times and this happens every few weeks. why does this happen and how can i fix it?

i tried reinstalling it multiple times, it works in the beginning and then changes the passowrd on it's own after a few days.

os: windows 10 pro. mysql version: 8.0

Comment: Please check: `SELECT @@default_password_expire;` and `SHOW CREATE USER CURRENT_USER;` Does your user definition include `EXPIRE DEFAULT` or some other term, and does the expiration term correspond to how long it takes for the password to change? For more information read about password expiration features: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/password-management.html

Comment: It would be really helpful to know the operating system and mysql version.

Comment: If you forget your password or lose access, you can follow the [instructions here to reset the root password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Comment: yaa it does include the "EXPIRE DEFAULT" term.
the full output i got was: 
| CREATE USER for root@localhost 
| CREATE USER `root`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED WITH 'caching_sha2_password' AS <a bunch of random stuff that i don't think i should share> REQUIRE NONE PASSWORD EXPIRE DEFAULT ACCOUNT UNLOCK PASSWORD HISTORY DEFAULT PASSWORD REUSE INTERVAL DEFAULT PASSWORD REQUIRE CURRENT DEFAULT |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix it this way:

```
ALTER USER <user>@<host> PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;
```

See the manual for more details on managing password expiration policies: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/password-management.html

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that the password wasn't a problem. the command line client was closing after entering the password, so i assumed that the password was causing the problem.
actually, once i to the control panel then administrative tools then component services then services(local) then i clicked on MySQL80. i found out that the service was not running. after starting the service the command line opened after entering the password and so did PopSQL.[image: the service was off]